# asp.net mvc model didn't receive on form submit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, model

I have written an asp.net mvc site that works fine on local.
But after publishing it, i have some problems with models sent from forms.
i think it determines my model state always not valid.
i don't receive any data!

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(Models.LoginViewModel data)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return LogIn();
        }
        TAPortalEntities db = new TAPortalEntities();

        UserAccount probableUser = db.UserAccounts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName == data.UserName && p.Pass == data.Pass);

        if (probableUser == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "نام کابری یا رمز عبور اشتباه وارد شده است!");
            return LogIn();
        }

        Session["LogedIn"] = true;
        Session["UserName"] = probableUser.UserName;
        Session["Course"] = probableUser.Course.Name;
        Session["TeacherName"] = probableUser.Course.TeacherName;
        Session["RealName"] = probableUser.RealName;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

and the view is like this:

```
@model TAPortal.Models.LoginViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ورود به سایت";
}

<h2>ورود</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>اطلاعات ورود را وارد کنید</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pass, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pass)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pass)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="ورود" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("برگشت به خانه", "Index","Home")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and the model class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TAPortal.Models
{
    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="نام کاربری باید وارد شود!")]
        [Display(Name="نام کاربری")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "رمز عبور باید وارد شود!")]
        [Display(Name = "رمز عبور")]
        public string Pass { get; set; }
    }
}
```

see these results:

input:

[image: input]

output local :

[image: out local]

output on online host :

[image: out online]

Comment: Why do you think you don't receive the data? Note `return LogIn();` should be `return View(data)` and if you add `[Required]` to your properties `UserName` and `Pass` then all you need to test is `if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(data); }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke `return LogIn();` is true . because you must return to the previous page to show the errors. i tried the thing you said but it stays in a loop. i mean it goes in HttpPost type of LogIn and calls itself and returns to its own place.

Comment: the reason that i know the model isn't send is that : when i leave one field free , in local mode i retrieve the of it and the other data comes back but when online , the page return with no data and whole errors.

Comment: I think you must post also your model class for let someone to answer

Comment: ok . i will . but the confusing thing is that when debugging with VS every thing works fine. but when online it doesn't.

Comment: Are you using IIS Express on your local? If so then switch over to using IIS and it should behave similarly.

Comment: I suggest you to write only      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(data);
        }

Comment: Another suggest, download Fiddler and see what your browser send in the form, this will sure help you

Comment: @theLaw , i have tried that. the if is right but the return View(data) doesn't work. it captures in a loop. and the fiddker was awsome but  the news is taht , the data is sent ok. the is something else. i think the asp uses some technology that is not supported in my host. i think something goes wrong. i want to throw my self from window out!

Comment: news: now i am sure that the form values is sent correctly to the server but thing is when i have it binded to my model , no data occurs. i think the asp finds my incoming data unacceptable. any idea?

Comment: @ConductedClever, Read my first comment again and study the docs for [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx). By using `return LogIn();` you are calling your `[HttpGet]Index()` method, not returning the current view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have the answer. I share it for the others who face this problem.

From first, every thing was correct but the wrong thing was the version of the .NET framework of my host. This type of coding requires .NET framework 4.5 but my host's .NET framework version was 4.0 and it was all the story.

Now I have transferred my code to a host of 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this filter

`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

to your POST Action

Edit:

in your get method instantiate your model and set to false the ValidationSummary

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
       var model = new LoginViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```